# Lagrange's Theorem (number theory) for higher powers of p

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If I understand correctly, Lagrange's Theorem shows that for odd prime $p$, $x^{p-1} - 1 \equiv_p 0$ has at most $p-1$ incongruent solutions modulo p.

Consider the congruence $x^{p-1} - 1 \equiv_{p^2} 0$. It is clear that any solution to this is a solution to the other congruence since $a \equiv_{p^2} b \implies a \equiv_p b$ for any $a$ and $b$. I believe that this implies that the first congruence has at most $p-1$ incongruent solutions modulo $p^2$ but am not certain how to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to prove this directly, but it is a consequence of the fact that $U(p^n)$ is cyclic since $U(p^n)$ has $p^{n-1}(p-1)$ elements and so $p-1$ is a divisor of the order. The fundamental theorem of cyclic groups tells us that there are exactly $d$ solutions for $x^d=1$ in a cyclic group when $d$ divides its order.

On the other hand, we can argue that the solutions of $x^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod {p^2}$ form a subgroup of $U(p^2)$ and so has order a divisor of $p(p-1)$. Since there are at least $p-1$ solutions coming from mod $p$, there are either $p-1$ or $p(p-1)$ solutions. But here again we need to know that there is an element of order $p(p-1)$, that is, that $U(p^2)$ is cyclic.